# click events don't reach root flash object

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I started using as3 a while ago, and mostly used starling instead of native flash objects. Today I decided to give a try to raw flash, and created a simple button:

```
private var _button: SimpleButton;

public function Main() 
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // entry point
    _button = new SimpleButton(new BUTTON); //BUTTON is an embedded bitmap
    addChild(_button);
    _button.useHandCursor = true;
    _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClick);
}

private function OnClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    trace("clicked");
}
```

This would definely work in starling, but I found that the click event won't dispatch to the button for some reason. Neither is hand cursor shown on mouse over. I tried mouse over, mouse up and other mouse events, but none of them work. I checked that the button is correctly added to stage. Also, when I add a mouse click event listener to the stage itself, clicks register normally. When I add a listener to Main, no events are registered again.
I'm probably misunderstanding something obvious. Maybe I need to dispatch events manually down to the children? But that would be strage, though. Or can it be a bug in FlashDevelop? Please, help.

Comment: How is SimpleButton defined?

Comment: Does Main extend MovieClip or Sprite? Is mouseEnabled true on the SimpleButton? Is mouseChildren true on Main?

Comment: @Amy Blankenship Yes, it extends flash.display.Sprite. I didn't set mouseEnabled explicitly, but I just tried setting this to true for both Main and SimpleButton, as well as explicitly setting mouseChildren to true. The result is the same however.

Comment: @Brian Standard flash SimpleButton http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html

Comment: What you're doing should work. However, the stage is so much more convenient so I usually use that instead of writing code to do things that are easy to do on stage. If the SimpleButton is added to the stage on the timeline, then all you have to do is addEventListener() in your constructor. Timeline objects are always added to the stage before the constructor runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of [`SimpleButton`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html#SimpleButton%28%29) takes 4 optional parameters:

> ```
> public function SimpleButton(upState:DisplayObject = null,
>                              overState:DisplayObject = null,
>                              downState:DisplayObject = null,    
>                              hitTestState:DisplayObject = null)`
> ```

of which you supply the first one (`upState`):

> ```
> _button = new SimpleButton(new BUTTON); //BUTTON is an embedded bitmap
> ```

The others default to `null`. That includes `hitTestState` which is the same as property of the class [`hitTestState`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html#hitTestState):

> Specifies a display object that is used as the hit testing object for the button. [...] **If you do not set the hitTestState property, the SimpleButton is inactive — it does not respond to user input events.**

It also includes a solution to your problem:

> For a basic button, set the hitTestState property to the same display object as the overState property.

However, **if all you want is to add click functionality to that `Bitmap`**, which it doesn't have on its own, because it's not an `InteractiveObject`, **simply use a `Sprite`**:

```
// entry point
_button = new Sprite();
_button.addChild(new BUTTON); //BUTTON is an embedded bitmap
addChild(_button);
_button.useHandCursor = true;
_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClick);
```

Use `SimpleButton` only if you want the functionality of its 4 states.

---

Please be careful with the overloaded term "stage":

> I checked that the button is correctly added to stage.

If you mean the "drawing area" that you can see in the Adobe Flash IDE or the main time line with "stage", then yes, you'd be correct that your button is added to that.

The `stage` property of `DisplayObject` however is something different. It's the top most element of the display list and the container that the instance of your `Main` class is added to, which happens at the start of the execution of your .swf in the FlashPlayer.

As your `Main` class adds the `_button` to itself by calling its own`addChild()`, the button is added to the instance of `Main` and **not** `stage`, which are two different objects.

Comment: Hey, null. I totally forgot about my question. That was very stupid of me to miss hitTestState. Thank you for your detailed explanation. Now everything works as expected.
By added to stage I meant that it is added to stage through its parent, i.e. there is a link between the added object and the stage, which is necessary for the object to be seen and interacted, I believe. And the event is also called ADDED_TO_STAGE, isn't it?

Comment: @Aikei it is. I just wanted to mention these two different meanings of "stage" because they often get confused with each other.